Solving a simple linear algebra system in Rust
I am trying to solve a simple linear algebra system (AX=b ) in Rust with the ndarry_linalg crate. This example code from their repo doesn’t compile:
use ndarray::prelude::*;
use ndarray_linalg::*;

fn main() {
    let a: Array2<f64> = array![[3., 2., -1.], [2., -2., 4.], [-2., 1., -2.]];
    let b: Array1<f64> = array![1., -2., 0.];
    let x = a.solve_into(b).unwrap();
    assert!(x.abs_diff_eq(&array![1., -2., -2.], 1e-9));
}

This come from the official doc: here of ndarray
This should work but when I run cargo build, the "compiler" does not find the method "solve_into" for ArrayBase.
I think I am missing something... Anyone has a hint ?

You probably have to import ndarray_linalg::solve::Solve. I suspect the compiler suggests that even. You should include the full compiler error in the question.

Since this is a problem with the example code from the repo, you will have better luck asking questions in the git repo itself. There is an issue already that talks about this: https://github.com/rust-ndarray/ndarray-linalg/issues/259.

And the source of this issue is that the crate ndarray_linalg isn't up to date with the latest ndarray version. Downgrade ndarray to 0.15

Might be a versoning issue
The current version ndarray_linalg = "0.16.0" use ndarray = "0.15.2" whereas you probably using later version e.g. "0.16.1". There are might be some breaking change that change the definition of ArrayBase<...>.
downgrade your ndarray
[dependencies]
ndarray-linalg = "0.16.0"

[dependencies.ndarray]
version = "0.15.2"
features = ["blas", "approx", "std"]
default-features = false

After that, the rust-analyzer stopped showing error.

"I got a linker error" - you likely need to depend on a blas/lapack implementation, see Link time error with ndarray-linalg with mkl-stats on Windows (don't have to use MKL, but you do have to use one of the "sources" listed here).
